# Which Browsers don't support ids for in page navigation (fragid)?

Tags: html, compatibility

In HTML5, [name is no longer a valid attribute of the anchor tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-diff-20080610/#absent-attributes) (`<a name="yadayada">`). It has [been mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id) that older browsers do not recognize the the new recommended approach (`<a id="yadaya">` or any `id` for that matter). What are the browsers which don't recognize ids for in page navigation ([fragids](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#scroll-to-fragid))? Are we talking about Netscape-era browsers or the usual suspect, Internet Explorer 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netscape-era. IE6 supports them just fine.

Answer (score 1):

IE 5 supports them too. Perhaps even IE 4.

Netscape 4.7 does not support id