# R anchors in markdown

Tags: r, knitr

In creating a Rmd file I included an internal hyperlink:

```
   [hlink](#id1)
```

and then further on an anchor

```
<a id="id1"></a> .
```

When I then use Knit HTML (in RStudio) everything works fine and the
internal hyperlink works fine but I also get an unwanted �

```
<p><a id="id1"></a>�</p>
```

How can I avoid getting this error?

Comment: Need a reproducible example as I can't reproduce this with RStudio 0.97.99, knitr .7, and markdown 0.5.2.  Care to provide your RStudio ver and sessionInfo() output?

Comment: Linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822089/how-to-link-to-part-of-the-same-document-in-markdown  and https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200842153-Anchor-all-headers-in-Rmd-and-or-automatic-tables-of-content

Answer (score 7):

I was just looking for a solution to produce a table of content and came across your question.

The above example works perfectly fine.
No unwanted side effects.

My session info:
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
knitr_1.1

Just wanted to mention that, incase somebody else comes across this question.