# R markdown anchor at the top of document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204257/r-anchors-in-markdown) I am trying to insert anchors in a long document so that users can easily navigate to the TOC of the document.

My code is as follows:

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
---
<a id="top"></a>

# First Section
```

Then I add `[Go to Top](#top)` wherever I want a link to go to the top of the document.

The problem I am having is that on clicking `Go to Top`, the page scrolls up such that `First Section` is at the top, not the Table of Contents (which is what I want). So the users have to scroll up again to go to TOC.

Is there any way to scroll back to the very top of the document, so that TOC is seen again on the page.

I tried to to put `<a id="top"></a>` before `---`, but that does not work.

Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: It should work with any kind of ID, so `<a href="#header">back to top</a>` should also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add you link somewhere and refers to `#header`...

```
<a href="#header">back to top</a>
```

Comment: This solution is great with `HTML` output but not for `PDF`.

Comment: That is true, didn't checked it on `PDF` and not sure how the hyper refs work in that case.