# Rmarkdown - blogdown: how to show yaml-generated table of contents when using anchor link to top of page

Tags: r-markdown, blogdown

I have this front matter on an Rmd page, with an anchor "top" after it:

```
---
title: "Runnymede"
weight: 500
output:
  blogdown::html_page:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 1
    number_sections: true
---

<a name="top"></a>
```

So when I click a 'back to top' link further down the page, the table of contents is not seen as it is still above where the anchor is on the page. Is there a way to anchor above the table of contents? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just found the answer to this: [R markdown anchor at the top of document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990622/r-markdown-anchor-at-the-top-of-document?rq=1)

Exact answer is slightly different though:

1. An anchor link can work with any ID
2. ID for table of contents is TOC (in above case)
3. so markdown for a link to go back to top of page and see the table of contents is `[Back to top](#TOC)`