# How to make a short link to specific code line from markdown in github issue text?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

How to make a short link to specific code line from markdown in github issue text?

I have read the question [How to link to specific line number on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821235/how-to-link-to-specific-line-number-on-github), but it's about putting full link in markdown.

My question is about some markdown shortcut, like `@user` or `#11 issue`

Doc [Autolinked references and URLs](https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/) doesn't help.

Comment: This would be a great feature to have. Unfortunate it doesn't exist now.

Comment: Besides the link being short, there is the issue of how to link to a specific *line* in a Markdown file within a GitHub repository, which is currently impossible, though there does exist an approximation by specifying in the URL what text to highlight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63197341/1959808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

When you use @user to point a user page or #17 for a specific issue in the current project, you create a link to a unique object. When you want to provide a link to a file code, maybe you want to point to the latest revision in master (ex: [https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/master/apitools/**init**.py](https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/master/apitools/__init__.py)) or on another branch (ex: [https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/csl-patch/apitools/**init**.py](https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/csl-patch/apitools/__init__.py)). As far as I know, there is no shortcut available in GitHub flavord markdown for linking to a specific file in the project.

As you already noticed, using this long form (the full URL), you will be able to add a #LXXX to the end of the URL to point to specific line in the file (ex: [https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/master/apitools/**init**.py#L5](https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/master/apitools/__init__.py#L5) or [https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/csl-patch/apitools/**init**.py#L8](https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/csl-patch/apitools/__init__.py#L8). But if you really want to avoid long links, you could use [GitHub URL Shortener](https://git.io/) to convert any link (with or without line number) to an equivalent short form: https://git.io/vMD6U