# How to go to a certain point of a different document in a .md file?

Tags: html, markdown

I am trying to go to a second part in the below mentioned .md file.
The file is Myfile.md.
its contents are:

```
    ## First part
    (an image)

    ## Second part
    (an image)
```

I am trying to access it from a html file by using the command

```
    <a href="some-url/Myfile#second-part">Second part</a>.
```

However, it is not pointing to the second part but pointing somewhere below that.
Can anyone tell me how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting, I found a solution using `<div…/>` but an obvious solution is to place your own anchor point in the page wherever you like, thus:

```
<a name="abcde"/>
```

before and

```
</a>
```

after the line you want to 'link' to. Then a markdown link like:

```
[link text](#abcde)
```

anywhere in the document takes you there.

The `<div…/>` solution inserts a "dummy" division just to add the id property, and this is potentially disruptive to the page structure, but the `<a name="abcde"/>` solution ought to be quite innocuous.

(PS: It might be OK to put the anchor in the line you wish to link to, as follows:

```
## <a name="head1"/>Heading One</a>
```

Please refer another question : [How to link to part of the same document in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822089/how-to-link-to-part-of-the-same-document-in-markdown)

Comment: this works if i want to move to a certain point in the same page, but i need to go from a different page. It's not working if I want to go from the first page to some point in the second page.

Comment: Please try : [a relative link](other_file.md#abcde)

Comment: Same as before. It works if I am in the same page but not in a different page.