# Automatically number sections in RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to create a report in R markdown that has sections ordered

1. Section 1 Header

   1.1 sub section 1

   1.2 sub section 3
2. Section 2 Header

   2.1

   2.2 sub section

   ```
     2.2.1 another sub section
   ```

Is there a way get R markdown to generate an ordered list like this?

Comment: Just use `# Sec 1`, `## Sub 1.1` and `### Sub 1.1.1`?

Comment: That will work. I was hoping for a method that generated the numbering automatically. That way if I wanted to go back and add in a section I wouldn't have to change the numbering system.

Comment: I dont get you. You dont need the numbers I added. They are just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: # Sec prints Sec as a header for me.

Comment: Check out the `number_sections: true` option....

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed. This is my first time using Rmarkdown so sorry if the question was super basic.

Comment: No worries. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 135):

Add the [option](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/html_document.html) `number_sections: true` to your YAML header:

```
---
title: "My Report"
output: 
  html_document:
    number_sections: true
---

# Main Section

## 2nd Level

### 3rd Level
```

And voilá, your sections are numbered:

[image: The above text in an image with numbered sections]

Comment: Is there a way to reference the automatically numbered section from within the markdown? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822089/how-to-link-to-part-of-the-same-document-in-markdown/58539106#58539106) asks how to link to a custom description; I want to get the generated section (or subsection) number.

Answer (score 0):

By setting "number_sections: true to your YAML header:" it is only possible to add numbers in the published html file, which is not friendly to the code writer.

Now here is a plugin for Rstudio that can fulfill your requirement to add or remove numbers in outlines:

***OutlineNum*** **: Automatically number sections for RMarkdown headers/outline in RStudio** Have you seen https://github.com/callAgene/OutlineNum

[Result of use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPuSf.png)