# Number some sections with rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing a manuscript with rmarkdown.

If I want to number all sections, I can use YAML like this

```
---
title: "My Report"
output: 
  html_document:
    number_sections: true
---
```

See [Automatically number sections in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120050/automatically-number-sections-in-rmarkdown/40157952)

But I only want to number some sections, so my document looks like

> **Abstract**
>    **1. Introduction**
>    **2. Methods**
>    **3. Results**
>    **References**

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Use [`# References {-}`](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#header-identifiers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the *Pandoc* [User Guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#header-identifiers) you want to add the `.unnumbered` attribute to the header. This is done using:

```
# My header {.unnumbered}
```

or the shortcut

```
# My header {-}
```

For example, using the following document

```
---
title: "My Report"
output: 
  html_document:
    number_sections: true
---

# Abstract {-}

# Introduction

# Methods

# Results

# References {-}
```

The HTML produced renders as:

[image]