# What is "fragment link navigation for Markdown" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

The February 2017 (version 1.10) release notes for Visual Studio Code describes something they call "Fragment link navigation for Markdown." Here is the description:

"Links to Markdown files that include a fragment will now try to open the file at the corresponding header:

```
* [Section](#_header)
* [Another file](./other_file#_header)

# Header
...
```

This allows quickly navigating documentation directly within the VS Code editor."

I've searched for any more information on this topic but haven't found anything. Fragments in Markdown? I didn't know that was possible. Can someone point me to more information?

Comment: This may help you understand what's meant by "fragment": [How to link to part of the same document in Markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2822089/866026). Presumably, VS Code is using the method described there under-the-hood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I implemented this feature. Sorry for the unclear documentation

In 1.9, we added support for <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>click</kbd> on links in the markdown editor to open the corresponding document.

```
Ctrl clicking [this link destination](./other_file.md) will open `other_file.md` in the editor
```

1.10 added support for navigating to a specific header in the current markdown file

```
Ctrl clicking [this link destination](#header) will scroll to # Header

... 

# Header
```

You can also use this across files:

```
Ctrl clicking [this link destination](./other-file.md#header) will open `other-file.md` and scroll to `#header`
```

This allows navigating markdown based documentation entirely within the editor. Here's the feature in action:

[image]

---

If you run into any bugs or have any feature suggestions for VSCode markdown support, please let us know: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: perhaps you should add that an ID is automatically assigned to each header which allows the hashs to work in links. Autogenerating IDs for headers, while common, is not a standard Markdown feature and not known by all Markdown users. Its not even mentioned in the Markdown Syntax rules. Seems to me the OP was confused about "fragments" for this reason.

Comment: Thanks, Matt -- I understand it now. I'm a technical writer and I'm all too aware of Markdown's shortcomings for efficient writing, such as no support for variable substitution or transclusion. I was hoping that "fragments" was a reference to a feature like that. This is a nice addition, though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, vscode v1.45 will be adding support to open **folders** referenced in markdown links in the explorer bar.  Akin to "Reveal In SideBar" but for folders.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#markdown-link-to-folders

> **Markdown link to folders**
>
> Editor links in markdown files and links in the markdown preview can
>   now point to folders. Clicking on one of these links will reveal the
>   target folder in VS Code's explorer.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70699884/836330 for an easy way to add links to markdown headers in the same or another files.