# Is it possible to get header links working in the markdown preview?

Tags: phpstorm, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have added a link to a header as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16426829/2734189). For example:

```
Here is a [link](#thing) to the thing.

... some other stuff

## Thing
```

PhpStorm [displays a preview of the rendered HTML](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/markdown.html), which is cool, but that link doesn't function, although it is displayed as a link, and other links to URLs outside the document do work.

Is there a way to make links like that work in the preview?

I was using the [default markdown plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7793-markdown-support), and I tried installing the [gfm plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7701-gfm), but that didn't work either, although the Gfm Preview is nice.

Also, I am assuming that my markdown for the link is correct and this is an issue with the preview, but I accept the possibility that I'm just doing it wrong. :) The gfm plugin's "Get HTML" function does show the link I expected, though
(`<a href="#thing">link</a>`) for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue, please follow [RUBY-21010](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-21010) for updates