# markdown & links to external markdown documents

Tags: markdown

It is possible to embed in a markdown document a link to an external document with syntax:
`[text in document](/path/to/document/otherdoc.md)`.

BUT:

Is it also possible to have a link in one document to a specific chapter in an external other document?

If it's possible, can somebody give a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: did you see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2822089/10321531)

Comment: Yes. That's all about links in the same document.
[some text](#link text) displays in the md document the "some text" in colour and when CTRL clik-on-it jumps to the text part that starts with ""link text".

That I have is this: (some text)[./OtherFile.md]. Then when clicking the coloured text a new md document opens.

What I need is a combination of both. Something like (some text)[./OtherFile.md#some text]. Click the coloured text and jump into a new document ending on a paragraph in teh document.  I tried that, and it does not work.

Comment: You can use absolute full link path if they will be served in some URL