# How would I jump to a point in a page using the hash or pound symbol(#) with a get variable?

Tags: php, hash, fragment-identifier

I found [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479511/So-You-Want-A-Page-Jump-Huh.htm) tutorial that explains what I want to do using html but when I echo out the code with a get variable there is no affect to the page. I would use, for example, the following code:

```
echo "<a href='post.php?id=".$id."#Comments'>Click here to go to the comments</a>";



echo "<a title='Comments'>Comments</a>";
```

I presume the problem is to do with the get variable, so would I have to end it, some how, before using the # symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem actually lies in your HTML, because the anchor should be parsed correctly by browsers regardless of the query string.

Page anchors use the `name` attribute instead of the `title` attribute:

```
<a name='Comments'>Comments</a>
```

You can also apply this to the `id` attribute of any element:

```
<h2 id='Comments'>Comments</h2>
```

Comment: +1 for speed, but you're better sticking with just `id`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Comment: That's strange... I was even following a tutorial! I think that's one of the stupidist mistakes I've made since staring php!! I just assumed it was something to do with the php because the html would have been too simple to make a mistake... obviously it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

To define jump-labels you have to set a name and/or id-attribute:

```
echo "<a title='Comments' name='Comments' id='Comments'>Comments</a>";
```