# How do I load a page and get it to open at a certain location of the loaded page?

Tags: html, anchor

For example, lets say I have `page1.html`, which has 3 links

```
<a href="page2.html#1">1</a>
<a href="page2.html#2">2</a>
<a href="page2.html#3">3</a>
```

on `page2.html`, I have those links on the page also, i.e.

```
<a href="page3.html#1">1</a>
<a href="page3.html#2">2</a>
<a href="page3.html#3">3</a>
```

but when I click on the `#2` or `#3` link from `page1.html`, they always open at the top of the page, even though `#2` and `#3` are off the screen on `page2.html` which need to be scrolled down to to be seen.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post an example of the html containing the anchors you have in place - e.g. <h2 name="2">Section Two</h2>

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to put *named* anchors on `page2.html`, like so:

```
<a id="1"></a>
…
<a id="2"></a>
…
<a id="3"></a>
```

Comment: Can these named anchors have href's in them too?

Comment: @oshirowanen Yes, that’s possible. However, for sanity’s sake I would separate these two concepts. That is, I would always leave anchors empty and use a separate tag for links. Or indeed anything else.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Does `id` work on browsers like IE7 etc?

Comment: is there any way to do it without an ID?

Comment: @bluejayke Why? What’s the problem with IDs?

Comment: @KonradRudolph the problem is that I don't have access to the source code, and I want to provide a link to a particular element on that page

Comment: @bluejayke You *do* have access to the source code, since that’s what your browser receives from the web server. You can inspect website source code in your browser using the developer tools. But unless the element in question has an ID set, you won’t be able to link directly to it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OK that was just my only question.. if you can put some kind of query selector in the URL, but I guess not

Comment: Many modern browser support some form of query selector in the hashtag, although this is non-standard.

Answer (score 26):

You need to add an ID to the element that it should 'jump' to.

For example, if you have

```
<div id="part1">
  <p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>

<div id="part2">
  <p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>

<div id="part3">
  <p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

And they are all in `page.html`

Then you can link to `page.html#part1`, `page.html#part2` etc etc and it will jump to the correct part of the page

Update:

You can also use the name attribute however I prefer to use id. This is because anything can have a id but not necessarily a name.  For example I don't think name is a valid attribute for an 'a' tag in HTML 5.  Also if you have one element with id="part1" and another different element with name="part1", the one with the id will take precendence.  To avoid confusion, I just stick with the one method throughout.  There's a bit more of a discussion on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

Comment: how to you make it jump to another radio navigation tab?

Answer (score 8):

Use of the name attribute or id attribute in an anchor tag on the **target** page would accomplish the desired result.

```
<a name="someLocation" id="someLocation">SomeText</a>
```

As an XHTML 1.1 convention, the name attribute of an anchor tag has been replaced by the id attribute. In the context of XHTML 1.0, the name attribute is considered deprecated.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id) for a related discussion on changes to the anchor tag.

To summarize: for compatibility reasons, many suggest the use of both an id attribute and a name attribute, within the same element. In this case, an anchor tag.

[The W3C Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3) recommends (with respect to all applicable elements):

> The id and name attributes share the same name space. This means that they cannot both define an anchor with the same name in the same document. It is permissible to use both attributes to specify an element's unique identifier for the following elements: A, APPLET, FORM, FRAME, IFRAME, IMG, and MAP. When both attributes are used on a single element, their values must be identical.

Apologies for any duplication, I lack the reputation to comment on the best answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  you need both ID and Name  <a href="#jumpToHere">Jump</a>
 <a name="studyTheStat" id="studyTheStat">Here</a>

Answer (score 6):

Since this posts are still found, i would like to add an update:

Fragment as Link

```html
<a href="#jumppoint">goto '#jumppoint'</a>
```

does jump to ID:

```html
<div id="jumppoint">  <!-- name="" does not work here on modern browsers -->
   <h2>here</h2>
</div>
```

and Named-Anchor:

```html
<a name="jumppoint" />
<h2>here</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

Either name your anchors or put links to your elements:

www.yoursite/index.html#content
Will scroll you to `<div id="content">` if it exists, or to `<div name="content">`.

Answer (score 0):

you must assign section names or ids 1 , 2 and 3 to sections , then it will work for you..