# Make a-tag scroll/jump to a div with *only* html5 and css?

Tags: css, html

I have an  which scrolls (animated) to a div with JavaScript on my one-pager website.

Now I would like to enable the user to do kind of the same thing when JavaScript is disabled. So at least the user should be able to jump to the div with the same link.

Is there a possibility to do so, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use anchor tags.

```
<a href="#foo">go to foo</a>

<p>some long text</p>

<p id="foo">this is foo</p>
```

It's been discussed in great detail here: [hash in anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582233/hash-in-anchor-tags)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use an pixel-offset for that scrollposition? (I'm dealing with a fixed positioned navbar so it doesn't scroll exactly to the right position now)

Comment: Nope, no way. Browser decides what to do, you have no control over it. You could use some `0px` high elements with IDs on them and jump to those. You could then position them wherever you need.