# Move to a <section> when click on an <a> in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I would like to know how to scroll to a `<section>` element on my page when cliking on an `<a>` element, both placed in the same page.

Thank you all in advance.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollIt.js can help you in this regard.

http://bytemuse.com/scrollIt.js/

4 simple steps and you're done

Answer (score 7):

This is a native and easier way to do this. You just have to give id to your section (or any HTML element) in the href attribute of the ancher tag.

Sample snippet:

```
<a href="#sectionId">GO to section</a>

<section id="sectionId">

//your code

</section>
```

[The W3C Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it (in pure HTML) putting hashes in your anchor tags as described on this question: [hash in anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582233/hash-in-anchor-tags/6582283#6582283)