# How to create a Hyper Jump in a Single post from one title to another

Tags: html

My problem is that I want to create an hyper Jump in my WordPress website; i.e. In the Beginning of the article there are 5 categories :

```
Category A
Category B
Category C
Category 5
Uncategorized
```

So whenever a person click on Category B, it scroll down to that particular topic down in that particular post. How to achieve this?

I've tried

```
<a href="#this-is-my-id">Category B</a>
```

To the Hyper Jump Link

```
<div id="#this-is-my-id">Category B substitute</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a `#` in your div's `id`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582233/hash-in-anchor-tags

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#this-is-my-id">Category B</a>

<div id="this-is-my-id">Category B substitute</div>
```

Remove # in the ID of div.

The above code will works!!

Comment: mentioned link not openin :(