# When I return redirect, I need to end up in same location on page as previous

Tags: jquery, html, css, mysql, python-2.7

I've built a small forum with messages and comments section. I'm using Python, Flask, MySQL, jQuery, and of course HTML & CSS. My question is when a user posts a message or a comment to that message, the page obviously returns redirect to that page. When that happens it always loads back to the top of the page and you have to scroll back to your message/comment. Is there a way for it to end up back on that page and at the spot of the message/comment you posted?

Comment: There's zero source code here, which means it's anyone's guess what's wrong.

Comment: You can use hash values in your redirect to direct the browser to a specific anchor on the page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582233/hash-in-anchor-tags

Comment: I can add all my code if you want, but I'm not sure what to add. I'm not even sure where a feature like this would go. Python, jQuery? I have no idea that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

You doesnt provide any code, i guess your comment box must be a form, add an id to that form say #comment_box ,now in the action add #comment_box, this will make the browser to scroll down to the comment box after submitting the form

```
<form action="/#comment_box" id="comment_box">
  <input name="comment" type="text" />
</form>
```