# installing map on website

Tags: html, css

I have an `image of a country` for `my website`.

> Is there a way I can add points to different areas on the map linking
>   it to a picture of location with a paragraph explaining about the
>   location ?

For example click on Bangkok on the map which takes you to image and paragraph with brief description of the city.

Every time I search online for an answer the only thing that keeps coming up is Google maps. Which is not want I want!

Thanks in advance

Comment: The thing you are describing is know as an "image map". There is a [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) tag for this purpose. "Map" here does not refer to cartography but an element that is used to define areas on an image that can be clicked.

Comment: Do you mean to navigate through the current page? Then use hash tag in the URL such as ....#Bangkok and in your paragraph use named anchor `<a name="Bangkok"></a>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582233/hash-in-anchor-tags

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am still struggling to get understand though.. so how would i get multiple areas to click on the image and then navigate to paragraph in same page(next to map) ?

Comment: here is my code for this so far.. 
<section class="section-places">
            <h2>places</h2>
        
            
            <p><a name="bangkok-map"></a> This is Bangkok..... </p>
         
            <img class="thai-map" src="resources/css/img/thailand-1861891_1920.png" alt="Thai-Map" usemap="#mapbangkok">
            
            <map name="bangkok">
            <area shape="circle" coords="50,0,82,126" alt="Bangkok" href="#">
                        
                
            </map>
        
        </section>

Answer (score 0):

[`<map>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) tag is what you need.

For [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap) visit this site. The only difficulty lies in the coords but if you use firefox you can use the ruler thing in the ToolBox to measure the height & width from the left-corner of the image .