# Using HTML to make link to an item on another page

Tags: html, google-sites

I'd like to have links in one page of Google Sites that the user can click to go to a position on another page, not just at the top of that page. ...got any hints as to how to do this?
For example, embedding HTML

```
<a href="https://www.whatever.com/1-my-divine-mission#My_New_Reality">My New Reality</a>
```

on a starting page, I would like to jump to `<p id="1-my-divine-mission/My_New_Reality">My New Reality</p>`

but it always goes to the top of the destination page. This ought to work, seems like, but doesn't. Neither does using the full web address in the id= portion of the code.

Can you perhaps modify the entry in the little "chain" link marker to refer to the id?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582233/hash-in-anchor-tags  OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash These can solve you problem

Comment: When all else fails, read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page).

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` shouldn't include the page path:

```html
<p id="My_New_Reality">My New Reality</p>
```

Your `<a />` will then go to the page `https://www.whatever.com/1-my-divine-mission` and scroll to the section with the `id` #My_New_Reality.

Comment: Sorry. That doesn't work in Google Sites. ...and no, the docs don't answer the question either. The docs entry only handles jumps on the same page.

Comment: That's strange. I'm not sure what to do then, but good luck.