# How to implement jump to <a name=... in post form

Tags: php, html

I have long list of products and in each product i have form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="prodid" value="<?= $id ?>" />
    ...
</form>
```

I want to jump to product on call action like:

```
<a href="#prodid<?= $id ?>">jump to product</a>
...

<a name="prodid<?= $id ?>"></a>
```

but i must use post method. In get method I would use this:

```
<form action="index.php#prodid<?= $id ?>" method="get">
    ...
</form>
```

How to do it?

Comment: the technique is the same, it only depends on getting the variables via either GET or POST... I don't understant where's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `<a name="..."></a>` for a jump-mark is deprecated in HTML5 as the `a`-element has no `name`-attribute anymore. See here: [HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id) and in the [specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element).

You can jump to anything on the site with a specified `id`-attribute by adding the `#[id]` to the URL (or creating a link like `<a href="#[id]">jump</a>`).

Adding the hashtag does not have anything to do with GET or POST. It's just a Browser-Feature.

Comment: name is only deprecated in xhtml, it's still valid in html. See http://derickrethans.nl/html-name-attribute-deprecated.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id.

Comment: @Steve Its not, there is no `name`-attribute in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

What about simple:

```
<form action="index.php#prodid<?= $id ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="prodid" value="<?= $id ?>" />
    ...
</form>
```

You will use both - hidden input and anchor in action.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you can still use `#prodid=x` syntax even with "post" methods.  `POST` method only controls how the data is sent to the server.

When the browser displays the target page of the form, it will see the `#anchor` and scroll the page accordingly.  Moreover, you can submit the form without the tag and then inside your processing script have something like this:

```
// process everything as required
...
header("location: mypage.php#prodid=$prodid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax to create a bookmark on the page for each product:

```
<a name="prodid<?= $id ?>">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="prodid" value="<?= $id ?>" />
        ...
    </form>
</a>
```

If you are writing xhtml/html5 drop the name attribute then you can use:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="prodid<?= $id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="prodid" value="<?= $id ?>" />
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but i must use post method.

No, you don't need that.
GET method is all right.

Answer (score 0):

For a long list of similar items, the way I use the most is an interator and a prefix. It gives me a context in which every items are ordered and each one can be jumped to with : `<a href="#section24">Additionnal information</a>`