# Setting height of a DIV to correspond with location of anchor inside said DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, show-hide

**Core issue** :  http://jsfiddle.net/pipip/P46Xg/
I have a `div` container with a few paragraphs of text,
and inside one of these paragraphs is the following anchor `<a name="stop" />`
The container is set to `overflow:hidden`

Is it possible with javascript / JQuery to set the height of the container so that the bottom of the container stops exactly at or below the anchor?

**Added Depth & Background**  : http://jsfiddle.net/pipip/yj9dB/
This would be used for a modified JQuery Slider. Where someone using a CMS could type `[readmore]` *anywhere* into the Content field, which would be replaced by the above  anchor via PHP. This way they would be easily able to control where the Read More break appears within the container.  In the associated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pipip/yj9dB/) I am hard-coding the height to `75px`, although what I want is for the height to be dependent on the location of the anchor `name="stop"` in the text.

Thanks. If this is an awful way to go about it, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With jQuery you could do it like this:

```
$('#container').height( $('a[name=stop]').position()['top'] );
```

and CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
```

We need this because `.position()` [gives us the position relative to an element's offset parent](http://api.jquery.com/position/), and we can make `#container` the offset parent of the anchor tag by setting its `position` to `relative`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/divad12/RYPm7/1/

Also, for HTML5, you may want to consider setting an anchor tag's `id` attribute instead of `name`: [HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks. I am now a victim of this site's game mechanics. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I took the basis of what you used and updated my Complete show/hide test: http://jsfiddle.net/pipip/MheSm/ Thank you for the note about using `id` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Still, the best way is to make the link load the full article via Ajax.