# How to use an HTML # anchor in a dynamic URL

Tags: html

I want to link to a section of a dynamic page using the `#` anchor. Something like this:

```
<a href=page.php?id=3#section-name>LINK</a>
```

It didn't work. What is the right way to do it?

I'm not using a direct link, but a redirect like `header("Location:page.php?id=3#section-name")` from another script.

I have a section named `section-name` in file *page.php*. I guess *page.php* has a problem figuring out the value of the id to process (`3` or `3#section-name`). I am redirected to *page.php* which has its content repeated vertically.

Comment: Share the other piece of markup. What does the html look like for the anchor tag you want to scroll to?

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work?" No browser loading? Directed to a wrong page? Are you missing double quotes or were they removed when you typed them in to the editor?

Comment: Does the page have an element with a name of `section-name`?

Comment: @Anthony Choi: It probably means the browser doesn't scroll to where "section-name" is in that generated ("dynamic") page.

Answer (score 5):

You've only presented half of your code so I can only give a sample of the proper way to do it:

```
<body> 
    <a name="top"> </a>
    <a href="#top">
        Go To Top Of Page
    </a>     
</body>
```

Comment: The question was about a "dynamic" URL, one with "?" - `?id=3` in the example. Not a static HTML page.

Answer (score 5):

When using anchor tags, you can target an element by its ID. Browsers will look for the ID before it looks for the `name` attribute when the link refers to such.

`<a href="#section-name>LINK</a>` will go directly to `<div id="section-name">` if it exists.

**[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/MPTJq/)**

Read: [HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

Comment: The question was about a "dynamic" URL, one with "?" - `?id=3` in the example. Not a static HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

#### A typical anchor tag works as follows:

A *href* link tag is written like so:

```
<a href="anchor_example2.html#a001">Jump to a001</a>
```

See the #a001 above? That is referencing an id in the HTML page, and it will jump to it if you click this link.

To provide an example of how this id that we would jump to might look on a page, look below.

```
<li id="a001">text here</li>
```

[Reference](http://www.tagindex.net/html/link/a_name2.html)

Comment: The question was about a "dynamic" URL, one with "?" - `?id=3` in the example. Not a static HTML page.