# Is it possible to create a link to a tag in an HTML page that isn't yours?

Tags: html

I know how to link to an anchor tag in my own code, and I also know how to link to another server's URL. However, If I want to create a (hyper)link in, say, a Word document, that will not only bring the user to a designated URL but will also scroll to a specific place on that HTML page *specifically if I am NOT the developer of the page?*

It doesn't look like this is possible, but I thought I'd ask.

Thanks.

Comment: A URL anchor refers to an element on the page. Without the reference, it won't scroll the page. So unfortunately no, this cannot be done.

Comment: @Santi That's kind of what I figured, although I was hoping there was a chance. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: If an `<a>` with the associated `name` attribute exists, you can append it to your URL. However, you cannot *add* an anchor that doesn't already exist.

Comment: you can link down the page to any `[id]` attribute, and there was a proposal I read at one point about allowing some sort of CSS selector in URLs to be able to deep-link to content within pages. I can't seem to find it though, and I can pretty much guarantee that it isn't implemented.

Comment: [It appears wikipedia has a section about proposals wrt deep linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Proposals).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I link to part of a page? (hash?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, provided there is somewhere in the page that you can anchor to. This would be the value of an element's name or id.

For more information, use the following link.  Please note, I've included an anchor to the answers section in the URL. 
[How to use HTML # anchor in a dynamic url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096614/how-to-use-html-anchor-in-a-dynamic-url#answers)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096614/how-to-use-html-anchor-in-a-dynamic-url#answers
```

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question correctly you can. To link to a specific section of a page, that has to be given a name with the `<a name="hello"></a>` and to link to that, lets have a dummy url to the page as: `http://example.com/page`. Now to link to that part specifically, just add `#hello` to the url, to give `http://example.com/page#hello`.