# is it possible to have non header anchors in markdown?

Tags: markdown

Is it possible to have an anchor in markdown that is not a header that begins with the #key.
What I would like is a way to link to any point in a markdown text rather than just a header.

Comment: What Markdown processor are you using?

Comment: The Markdown-it processor

Comment: If you have HTML enabled, you can simply use the `name` property of `a`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @Simple Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12096614/3151675).