# direct users to specific locations in page

Tags: html, fragment-identifier

I want to set up a menu to direct the user to the same page, but diffent locations

```
  <ul>
      <li><a href="realtime.php#location1">location 1 in page</a></li>
      <li><a href="realtime.php#location2">location 2 in page</a></li>                
   </ul>
```

here is the page's html: (realtime.php)

```
 <div id="location1" name="location1"></div>
    <some html....>
    <div id="location1" name="location1"></div>
    <some other html...>
```

It doesn't work for me:
1. It doesn't redirect to the correct location inside the page
2. If I'm viewing the current page, It does nothing -> meaning doesn't even reload the page.

Comment: if your url and your anchors have different names, how could they work?  `location1` cannot find `squeeze` or `ETF`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Comment: hi @dnagirl , thanks for the reply. I have corrected the errors. It is still not working..

Answer (score 1):

The fragment identifiers have to match the id of the element that is being targeted.

If you want to link to `id="squeeze"` then you need `#squeeze` not `#location1`

I also recommend avoiding linking to `<a>` elements in favour of a block element containing the content you want to link to.

```
<div id="sequeeze">
```

Comment: hi Quentin, please see edits in msg body. It's still not working

Comment: @devmonster — Your HTML is invalid with made-up `name` attributes and duplicate IDs. If you make it valid and put the content in the divs as I said, then it works: http://jsfiddle.net/dB3gH/

Comment: Hi Quentin, I see that your code works. but mine still isn't. I have entered my code to [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dB3gH/1/) to see exactly why and it works in jsfiddle but not in my page. My page in a regular html5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` page. The divs contain iframe, though. maybe that the reason..

Answer (score 0):

just use links with anchors

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li><a href="#location1">location 1 in page</a></li>
>   <li><a href="#location2">location 2 in page</a></li>                    
> </ul>
> ```

than inside the body

```
<div id="location1"></div>
```