# in HTML, url contains #, scroll page to header?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, header

If my url is something like: http://www.thisisawebsite.com/page.php#about 
How do i make it so when the link is clicked, it'll go to the header "about", or anywhere else i so desire?

Comment: Look at this. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to define the anchor in your markup (near your 'About' header):

```
<a name="about"></a>
```

Anyone else having a question about this should explore using an `ID` attribute on the actual element they want to link to:

```
<h1 id="about">About</h1>
```

**UPDATE**
As mentioned by some in the comments, `name` is a deprecated attribute on the `a` tag:

> Was required to define a possible target location in a page. In HTML 4.01, id and name could both be used on , as long as they had identical values.
>
> Note: Use the global attribute id instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: You're welcome. If that works for you, please feel free to 'Accept' this answer.

Comment: Is that what the questioner is asking?  I thought you wanted to go to the <h1>about</h1> on your page.php when someone clicks on a link in the format http://www.thisisawebsite.com/page.php#about in which case the answer is to markup the h1 itself with <h1 id="about>About</h1>. I've added this as an answer.

Comment: 6 of one, 1/2 dozen of the other. (Cool, though. Didn't know you could do it that way.) +1 for teaching me something new

Comment: :-) ID elements are the swiss army knife of HTML

Comment: Thanks also, i'll use kevin's method though considering I'm not using an actual header, just text that is bold (and appears bigger than most of the other text).

Comment: Hmm... but it's not the anchor you need to give the name - it's the element you want to be the target on the page.  So the text in this case - it can be a span whatever.  You should put the ID on the correct element NOT on an <a> tag somewhere nearby.  That's not the correct approach, and it's not the correct answer for others coming here and referencing this.

Comment: The `name` attribute (for `a` and some other elements) is [obsolete in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-a-name). Use `id` instead, as Richard Jordan suggested in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13040490/1591669).

Answer (score 11):

Just markup the header on the target page with the id "about" i.e.

About

That way your link on the linking page http://www.thisisawebsite.com/page.php#about will go straight to the "about" header - a h1 in this example but it could be whatever you'd given the id of "about".  Remember you should only use the id "about" once on the page though.

Comment: I did forget to thank you for your answer as well. I will use yours considering i found it it can be used as an attribute an pretty much all tags, while name only works with a few...