# In page anchor not working in firefox

Tags: html, anchor

I have got my code something like below which repeats to the number of shots varying for every page. My aim is to open a popup and go to that particular shot straight by url like

`www.example.com/shot/#12`.

For some reason this works fine in IE and chrome but does no in Firefox. In Firefox it gets pointed to something different but does open the popup.

```
<repeater>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="#ShotNumber" name="#12">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            HTML FOR EACH SHOT
        <div>
    <div>
<repeater>
```

Comment: Try using id="12" insted of name="#12".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ANCHOR

```
<a name="Anchorname"></a>
```

for example: normal way

```
 <div>
   <a href="#ShotNumber">Go to ShotNumber</a> <!-- Link to ShotNumber -->
   <a href="#12">Go to 12</a> <!-- Link to 12-->
 </div>
 <!-- more stuff -->
 <div>
   <a name="ShotNumber"></a> <!-- Anchor name=ShotNumber -->
   HTML FOR ShotNumber
 </div>
 <!-- more stuff -->
 <div>
   <a name="12"></a> <!-- Anchor name=12 -->
   HTML FOR 12
 </div>
```

Call it like:

```
example.com/myShot.html#ShotNumber
```

**EDIT:** [html5: the-indicated-part-of-the-document](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-indicated-part-of-the-document)

If there is an element in the DOM that has an **ID** exactly equal to decoded fragid, then the first such element in tree order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.

If there is an **a** element in the DOM that has a **name** attribute whose value is exactly equal to fragid (not decoded fragid), then the first such element in tree order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.

Comment: i reckon 'name' is not among valid html 5 attributes (on anchor at least). I have tried using Id, but again I dont understand why different browsers are behaving differently !!

Comment: ** One more thing... I finally fixed it today. It was a styling issue. The height of the div was 0 ie. no layout. I included layout on it and it works like a charm (except ie8)... still struggling with that though.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`<a name="12">This is item number 12</a>`

and then 
`<a href="#12">Go to item number 12</a>`.

Also, the anchor id thing is not supported in HTML5, they say. [This might be of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id).

Comment: In your link, I wouldsay it should be either `<h1 id="xxx" tabindex="-1">` or `<a name="xxx" id="xxx"></a>`

Comment: Yeah, my example above is the old fashioned way.