# Linking to an id not working in Firefox - Working in Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I am trying to link to a specific id on another page in a rails app.  The html markup that I am targeting is:

```
<h3 id="about">About</h3>
```

When I manually put localhost:3000/#about into the browser address bar, it opens up to the correct spot in the page in Chrome and Safari.  But when I paste that path into Firefox, it seems to stall - it opens up midway through the first page.  Then if I hit enter on my keyboard again in the address bar, it goes to the correct spot.

Any ideas what may be causing this?  Curious if I am following the correct conventions and have already taken a look at this excellent post -  [HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id).

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: What Firefox version(s) have you tried it in?

Comment: Try this link, http://support.mozilla.org/sv/questions/927172#answer-332591. Does that work? Do you add contents to the DOM with Javascript?

Comment: I have only tried it in Firefox 19.0.2.  The link you sent does work.  I am using a jquery pagescroller plugin which could be causing issues.  Was hoping to hear an easy Firefox remedy.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer but if there is a pagescroller script, that might be the bug in Firefox and not the browser itself. It might be a known issue for the script, have you checked?

Comment: Thanks for the response - I did search with that in mind and didn't find anything helpful.  Other people seem to be able to solve their problem by disabling js, but I tried and it still is not working.  A live example can be seen here by clicking the 'About' nav link at the top - http://www.officescholar.com/topics/89

Comment: Either it's the pagescroller plugin or the use of other plugins, like loader.js in conjunction; ie Something is disrupting the load. Try to simplify and remove anything except jQuery and the pagescroll plugin. Does it work then? If yes, something else is the issue. If not, the plugin is the issue. I also noted that on their own pagescroller.com they use jQuery 1.7.1. Might be worth a try aswell.

Comment: This might help you, it helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163841/in-page-anchor-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try exactly anchors thats given below and tell me if its working or not.

```
 <div class="one">   <a href="#details">Click Here To Go There</a> </div>

 <div class="two">   <a name="details">There</a> </div>
```

You have to position the div classes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - gave this a shot locally and still not working in Firefox.  A live example can be found at officescholar.com/topics/89 after clicking 'About' in the top nav.  Appreciate the suggestion!