# Should I specify anchors with an anchor element?

Tags: html, anchor

In the past I've seen examples of anchors being specified using anchor elements, and `id` or `name` attributes ([with id taking precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)).

However, is there any particular reason why I should use an anchor element over any other element, in terms of accessibility/cross-browser support?

For example I could a URL http://domain.com/page.htm#faq with the following markup:

```
<a id="faq"></a>
<h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
```

Which could be simplified to:

```
<h1 id="faq">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
```

Is there any harm in using this second markup? Is there a particular reason why developers would prefer empty anchors over attaching the `id` to a more relevant element?

Comment: I've _never_ used the first method. I don't see anything wrong with the second, I use it all the time. Probably remnants of the past.

Comment: @Christian - you are too young to remember ;) Indeed, remnants of the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any particular reason why I should use an anchor element over any other element, in terms of accessibility/cross-browser support?

No, not any more.

Historically (pre HTML 4), named anchors were the only way to have in page anchors.

> Is there any harm in using this second markup?

That's the recommended way - that's how you should do it.

> Is there a particular reason why developers would prefer empty anchors over attaching the id to a more relevant element?

Only lack of learning and adapting to change ;)

Comment: +1 Thanks Oded, this has give me the reassurance to continue using the 2nd method without worrying that I'm blocking out x% of users!

Comment: @Curt - Only those using Mozilla 3, IE 3.02 and such ;)

Comment: Ha, well I'm more than happy to block them out!

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to write your code. There are two points of using first code:

1. Historical reasons.
2. HtmlHelpers in any html-drive, like Razor. For example, it looks fine for me to use something like this:

   ```
   public static MvcHtmlString Anchor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string anchorId)
   {
       var tag = new TagBuilder("a");
       tag.Attributes.Add("id", anchorId);
       return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
   }
   ```

In my MVC project.