# how to scroll down a page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two Divs with skip `hrefs` upon clicking the first `href` skip  it should automatically scroll down to the next div.

I have tried like this

```
<div class="skip"><a href='javascript:move_down()' onclick="skipWindow(2);">skip</a></div>

 function move_down() {        
   window.scrollBy(0, 50);
 }
```

Comment: Many JavaScript frameworks have methods to make this sort of thing easier.  For example, dojo has scrollIntoView().   Check out the documentation of your preferred framework.

Comment: function showIt(elId) {
         var el = document.getElementById(elId);
         el.scrollIntoView(true); I tried like this bu tit has not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with using an anchor link, or in HTML5 terms, a fragment. No JS required (although JS could insert the correct link/fragment if that's needed dynamically).

See
[HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)