# Anchor click and keeping page position?

Tags: javascript, html

In my page there are some anchor that has no link, like this:

```
<a href="#">Anchor</a>
```

When I click anchor that is bottom of the page, Page is scrolling to top. I want to keep page position, if I clicked the link. How Can I do this. (no js is better for me)

I hope, I could explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll still have to use JS, but you can do it inline:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Test</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7ppZT/**

Alternatively, you can capture the event:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @AliRiza FYI you'll need JQuery for the alternative.

Comment: @Steve, Yes there are a lot of link like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can put anchors in anywhere in the page where you want it to go.

```
<a href="#stophere">Anchor</a>

<a id='stophere'>Bottom Of Page</a>
```

Then, the link will go to the named anchor.  Just stick in that element wherever you want to stop.

Comment: thats true but you should use the id instead of the name

Comment: Thanks, But I dont want to go special place. I want it to keep its position.

Comment: @F.Müller - ahh, you're right.  Thanks, I did not know that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi - you have to tell the page to go to that position.  You can do that using named anchors (or Javascript).  Maybe you want to add the `javascript` tag to your question?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi the thought is to give the link an id and then you have the link pointing to itself ...

Comment: yes you right. But I thougt there may be a way to do it without js.

Comment: This IS the way to do it without JS.  :)

Comment: There are widgets in my pages. And they have buttons as anchor, so I dont want page to move anywhere. If I use your suggestion, page will move. (I know not to top, but to another place). Great thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

to fix this issue , I use this code , **it's script solution but works on all browsers**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#noname">Anchor</a>
```

Make sure that `noname` you didn't use for `id` attribute of any tag or `name` attribute of `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set a name and add the name after the `#` like this

```
<a name="adsf" href="#adsf">Anchor</a>
```