# Use ERB to generate Anchor Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, anchor, erb

I'm trying to create Anchor tags using values in my DB for the name. That way it's easy for me to call them from another page.

```
<a name="<%= sailing_class.sort_order %>"</a>
```

But the value from sailing_class.sort_order never appears.

All help is greatly appreciated. I'm on Rails 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `>` (closing `<a`), so the html is not vaild, and an [anchor should be with an `id` attribute instead of `name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id) . Try

```
<a id="<%= sailing_class.sort_order %>"></a>
```

Comment: You should accept the answer then (the check at the left of the answer), and you should do so also for your other questions.