# Anchor to a section with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, anchor

i'm trying to create an anchor to a page's element. There's a tab interface. In html i can see that their links are like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php/service#tab-1
http://example.com/index.php/service#tab-2
http://example.com/index.php/service#tab-3
http://example.com/index.php/service#tab-4
```

So that i have 4 div's with id's tab-1,tab-2 etc.

How can i create anchor to them from another view file? When i try this:

```
<a href="<?=site_url();?>/service#tab-1">give it a try</a>
```

it goes to page /service but not focused on #tab-1 . It was working on plain html, but i couldnt do it with codeigniter

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the same thing on my CodeIgniter and it worked fine so I suggest double checking your IDs are correct. Other than that try

```
<a href="<?=site_url('/service#tab-1');?>">give it a try</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?=site_url('/service');?>#tab-1">give it a try</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the target of `#tab-1` etc. in your page. So in your div you need to include a named anchor such as:

```
<a name="tab-1"></>
```

This will cause the page to jump to this element.

Comment: Looking at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id It looks like using IDs rather than names is the accepted way to go about this, if I'm not mistaken