# Rails link_to anchor tag on other page not working in Firefox, but is working is Chrome and Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, hyperlink, anchor

In a rails app, I am linking to a specific anchor on another page.  It is working fine in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.  Would love to hear if anyone has any suggestions on syntax for linking to another anchor and controller/action.

```
# The link
<%= link_to 'About', root_path(:controller => "home", :anchor => "about") %>

# Destination on other page
<h3 class="dark"><a name="about" class="anchor-navigation">About</a></h3>
```

I have tried a number of things, including adding :action => "index", changing name in the html to id, and adding in parenthesis to make it clearer.  So far no dice in Firefox, but working fine with Chrome/Safari.  My guess is they are fixing something in the generated markup that FF isn't.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!  Thanks.

EDIT:  Also, when I manually paste in the url localhost:3000/#about in Chrome, it opens directly to the correct spot of the page, but doing the same thing in Firefox does not work.  It works in chrome with the markup above, as well as trying an id approach in the h3 tag:

```
<h3 class="dark" id="about">About</h3>
```

Comment: Very inscructive post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Comment: Changing my html to <h3 class="dark" id="about">About</h3> does not work with the existing link_to.  Any ideas?  Also tried changing :anchor to :id, #about and link_to "/#about" but still not working.  Going to edit with another finding that may describe the problem better.  Thanks.

Comment: Suggest you make this a more generic question. It seems to not be related to rails.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="#details">Click Here To Go There</a>

<a name="details">There</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working.  I've reposted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551621/linking-to-an-id-not-working-in-firefox-working-in-chrome-safari