# Stop from jumping to top of page

Tags: php, hyperlink, href

there is any method to prevent page to Stop from jumping to top of page when I click on a link, my link look like that:

```
 echo "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=remove&key=$nameskey\">Remove</a>";
```

This a link where to click when I want to delete a entry from a list ,

I'm using just PHP.

Thanks

Comment: You need to look up something called AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You either use ajax or a named anchor in the link that sends the user back down the page when it reloads.

Named anchor: [HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

Ajax method(one of MANY options): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code immediately. [This post](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/08/08/hey-you-deleted-my-files/) gives one reason why. `GET` requests should never modify anything on the server, especially not deleting.

Instead, you should look into using AJAX. For example:

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:remove(this,'".$nameskey."');\">Remove</a>";
```

And:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function remove(link,key) {
        var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
        a.open("POST","delete.php",true);
        a.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                // assuming the link is a direct child of the element to be removed
                link.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(link.parentNode);
            }
        };
        a.send("action=remove&key="+key);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The issue isn't with the inherent nature of GET requests, the issue is the lack of security and input/user validation.

Comment: I'm not deleting anything on the server I just  did a list of example some names and when I'm sure my list is complete(remove or adding) I submit my list.Of course my list come from a DB.