# Why does the link to top of page not go to a named anchor in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, hyperlink, internet-explorer-11

We have links in pages that should land a user on a specific page and scroll them to (a named anchor) near the middle of the page using the URL fragment #top. This works in every browser with the exception of Internet Explorer.

I am using Internet Explorer 11. As far as I know, this problem exists in all versions of IE.

This question is NOT about IE 8. The solution offered in a similar SO question doesn't work for me.

I've search all over and can't find examples of this being a problem and so I can't find solutions. In fact, I have found only one solution that describes the problem and provides a solution. However, their solution doesn't work for me.

I've moved little blocks of code here and there, but IE refuses to go to the named anchor. Why not?

A solution that doesn't work for us.
https://chrisjean.com/links-to-named-anchors-or-element-ids-fail-in-ie8/

Our link that should land the user in the middle of the page
http://www.av-iq.com/avcat/ctl1642/index.cfm?manufacturer=crestron-electronics&videos=6703#top

The named anchor on our page ...

```
 <a name="top"></a>
```

Example links on our pages...

```
<a href="index.cfm?manufacturer=crestron-electronics&videos=6702#top">
   next video
</a>
```

These do not work either ...

```
<a name="top" id="top"></a>
<a id="top"></a>
<div id="top"></a>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `<a id="top" name="top"></a>`?

Comment: @j08691 is right, you don't even need a `name` attribute, just change it to `id`

Comment: I edited the post. changing name to id doesn't work either. Still no effect in IE.

Comment: which IE version and can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Google is my friend :) It appears to be a known issue of IE8, but apparently you just have to use a element other than `a` https://chrisjean.com/links-to-named-anchors-or-element-ids-fail-in-ie8/ (can't test it, cross fingers) You may also try to put something into it, even just a `&nbsp;`

Comment: I have tried <div id="top"></a> with no luck. I am using Internet Explorer 11. As far as I know, no version of IE is working correctly.

Comment: "Beginning January 12, 2016, only the most current version of Internet Explorer available for a supported operating system will receive technical supports and security updates." https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with HTML links in Internet Explorer 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282878/problems-with-html-links-in-internet-explorer-8)