# document.getElementByName Code works fine on Firefox but doesn't work on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was using this code fine on bothe IE9 and Firefox but now it works only on Firefox and it just doesn't execute Java validation part on IE9. Any idea what I may need to do to make it work on both type of browserss?  Thanks

```
  <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $first_name=$_POST['fname'];
     echo 'Entered First Name = '.$first_name;
  }
  ?>
  <html>

  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
      <label for="fname"> First Name: </label> <input  type="text" name="fname"  /> <br /><br />
      <label for="file"> Select File: </label> <input  type="file" id="file" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

  <script>
  document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function( evt ) {
     var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

      if(file && file.size < 18000) { 
          //Submit form
         alert('Size is valid');
      } else {
         alert('pic too big');
         evt.preventDefault();
      }
  }, false);
  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: there is no `document.getElementByName` in this code

Comment: I can't imagine how it would work in FireFox either considering it's `getElementsByName()`.

Comment: Put the eventlistener in `window.onload`

Comment: Looks like the problem is with `var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];`

Comment: I don't see any Java code.

Comment: Prasath, how to put eventlistener in window.onload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the `files` array does not exist is not due to a code error.  Internet Explorer 9 and below [do not support](http://caniuse.com/fileapi) the [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), so you will have to use a workaround such as uploading with a Java applet or Adobe Flash.

Comment: Yes, it was IE9 issue. After upgrading to IE10, it is working fine. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Combined with what Alex W said, your code also needs some tweaking. `getElementsByName` requires a name attribute from where you are trying to select. It returns a NodeList of elements with the name given in the function. .

<s>Change your `input` to have a `name` attribute, then you won't even need that function:</s>

<s>`<input type="file" name="file" />`</s>
`id` works just fine. See below.

I stand corrected by my own research. All the above is true about `getElementsByName`, however to retrieve the `File` object, you have to call it from an array returned by selecting a file input form type. As such, `document.getElementById('file').files[0]` *should* work. So will the method below:

```
window.onload = (function () {
    document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
        //this works
        var file = document.forms[0].file.files[0];
        //as does this
        file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
        if (file && file.size < 18000) {
            //Submit form
            alert('Size is valid');
        } else {
            alert('pic too big');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/9N3L8/1/)**

Even after all is said and done, it still will not work in browsers that do not support the HTML5 File API (looking at you IE).

### Edit

Whoa, whoa, whoa hold the reigns? I just read that the `id` attribute was slated to replace the `name` attribute once IE6 gets nuked. Apparently this is old news<sup>[1](http://derickrethans.nl/html-name-attribute-deprecated.html) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id#comment301413_484781) [3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-attributes)</sup>.

So I did some testing and it turns out `id` works just fine when calling the element the same way:

```
var file = document.forms[0].file;
```

Prove it? [Ok](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/9N3L8/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a script error.

The `files` property does not seems to be supported in IE9

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function( evt ) {
    var f = document.getElementById('file');
    var file = f.files ? f.files[0] : f;

    if(file && file.size < 18000) { 
        //Submit form
        alert('Size is valid');
    } else {
        alert('pic too big');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GXcr9/)

Comment: It is working in Fiddle, but it doesn't work if I run it directly from my Apache server using IE9. Works in Firefox though. I even did my IE setting reset, but no luck.