# Getting a link to go to a specific section on another page

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I have a link on one page that needs to go to a different page, but load to a specific section on that other page.

I have done this before with bootstrap but they take all the 'coding' out of it, so I need to know how to do from scratch. Here is the markup I have based on this link (not the best resource, I know): http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

```
**Page One**
<a href="/academics/page.html#timeline> Click here </a>
**Page I am linking to**
<div id="timeline" name="timeline"> ... </div>
```

Can I do this with just HTML, or do I need some JavaScript? If I need to do it via JS, it needs to be on the target page, right?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe the example you've posted is using HTML5, [which allows you to](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html#scroll-to-fragid) jump to *any* DOM element with the matching `ID` attribute.  To support older browsers, you'll need to change:

```
<div id="timeline" name="timeline" ...>
```

To the old format:

```
<a name="timeline" />
```

You'll then be able to navigate to `/academics/page.html#timeline` and jump right to that section.

Also, check out this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id).

Comment: In this case "older browsers" are Netscape 4 and earlier and Internet Explorer 3 and earlier. Nobody needs to support them. On a related note, the anchor element doesn't have an optional end tag. You can't use the `/>` syntax in HTML.

Comment: If it's a react app then how to do that ??

Answer (score 16):

You can simply use

```
 <a href="directry/filename.html#section5" >click me</a>
```

to link to a section/id of another page by

Comment: It distorts the proportion (width percentage) of the page when navigated. Do you know why?

Comment: eg: <span id="section5"></span>

Answer (score 4):

To navigate to a section of another page use:

```
<a href="example.html#example-section">name-of-link</a>
```

The example.html would be the page you want to go to, and the #example-section would be the name of the id on that page that you want to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

To link from a page to another section of the page, I navigate through the page depending on the page's location to the other, at the URL bar, and add the #id. So what I mean;

`<a href = "../#the_part_that_you_want">This takes you #the_part_that_you_want at the page before</a>`

Answer (score -2):

I tried the above answer - using `page.html#ID_name` it gave me a *404 page doesn't exist* error.

Then instead of using `.html`, I simply put a slash `/` before the `#` and that worked fine. So my example on the sending page between the link tags looks like:

```
<a href= "http://my website.com/target-page/#El_Chorro">El Chorro</a>
```

Just use `/` instead of `.html`.

Comment: seems to not be accurate

Answer (score -3):

To link from a page to another section just use

```
<a href="index.php#firstdiv">my first div</a>
```

Comment: To link from a page to another section just use <a href="index.php#myFirstDiv">My First Dig</a>