# Link to part in long HTML file

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I want to create a hyperlink to a part in a long html page.

The page: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

I want to create a link to the part where this gets explained: `${parameter/pattern/string}`.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to [link to a specific part of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687328/getting-a-link-to-go-to-a-specific-section-on-another-page), you need to have an identifier to link to.

There is no way to design a link that points to an arbitrary position on a third-party page.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to create links to arbitrary parts of a web page.

Fragments ("anchors") that are intended to be linked to can be designated by assigning `id` attribute to their tags. That elements can be referenced using *fragment* part of URI, i.e. the part after `#`.

```
<p id="first">First paragraph</p>
<p id="second">Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
```

First two paragraphs can be linked to using `http://somewhere/.../#first` and `http://somewhere/.../#second` URIs, whereas it's not possible to target third paragraph, as it does not have `id` attribute.