# Relative Anchor Tags from the same page

Tags: html

I have a page at `http://mydomain/articles/20131114` I'd like to add an anchor to a comments section. Obviously I could add the full tag URL `http://mydomain/articles/20131114#Comments` but I'd also find it really useful at be able to add a relative anchor from inside the document (e.g. something like `#Comments`). I can't find much documentation on this question so I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

can you help
Thanks

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you can just do `<a href="#Comments">Link text</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a "named anchor"

From

```
<a href="#comments">Go to Comments</a>
```

Target:

```
<a name="comments">Here is the comments section</a>
```

Please note that newer browsers prefer an ID instead of name

[HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

That means you can keep the link but access any object with an id, which has to be unique

```
<h1 id="comments">Comments section</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and always has been possible. This will do what you want:

```
<a href="#Comments">Go to comments</a>
```

This will take you:

- either to an `a` element with the `name` `Comments`
- or to any element with the `id` `Comments`

I agree that it's a little hard to find a specification for this. The best one is probably the [specification for URIs, page 27](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-27):

> When a URI reference refers to a URI that is, aside from its fragment component (if any), identical to the base URI (Section 5.1), that reference is called a "same-document" reference.  The most frequent examples of same-document references are relative references that are empty or include only the number sign ("#") separator followed by a fragment identifier.