# jQuery hash-based nav with jquery-bbq makes page jump around

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-bbq

I have a site at www.tinytoepress.com that uses #hash anchor tag based navigation, using jQuery and the jquery-bbq plugin. It works great, except that sometimes it causes the page to jump down below the header as if it were going to an actual `<a name...>` tag. But there are no such tags.

For example, with Chrome on OS X if I visit the homepage:

http://www.tinytoepress.com/

and then click the "Store" link in the upper left, I go to:

http://www.tinytoepress.com/#store

However, I am scrolled down below the header, which is not desired. I would like to remain right at the top.

If I scroll up and click "About", I go the About page but again I'm scrolled down past the header. However, if I now scroll up to the top and click on "Store" again, I go to Store without scrolling down, which is desired.

I am using simple `.show()` and `.hide()` methods to controlling the visibility of the `div`s which are set from the nav clicks.

Any ideas how to prevent jumping around in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default browser behaviour when the hash address is changed is to jump to the id that represents the hash. For example: `http://example.com/some-page#store` will search on the page the element with id `store` (`<div id="store">...</div>`). If this is found, the page will jump there.

Instead of setting the id attribute I suggest you to set a custom `data-attr` attribute.

`<div id="store">...</div>` will become `<div data-page="store">...</div>` and in the jQuery side you will replace `$(location.hash).show()` with:

```
$("[data-page='" + location.hash.substring(1) + "']").show()
```

The code will look like below:

```
$("a").on("click", function () {

    // get the clicked link
    var $clickedLink = $(this);

    // get the url
    var url = $clickedLink.attr("href");

    // we search the hashes
    if (url[0]  !== "#") { return; }

    // change the location using js
    location.hash= url;

    // hide all pages
    $("[data-page]").hide();

    // show the current page
    $("[data-page='" + url.substring(1) + "']").show();

    // prevent the default browser behaviour (jumping)
    return false;
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5SRgp/)

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea that #foo would also target < ... id="foo"> -- I thought it was only for <a name="foo">. Very good to know. Thanks, I really appreciate the information!

Comment: Some more context on this correct answer from イオニカ ビザウ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, can't replicate your issue (running OS X 10.9 with Google Chrome 31.0.1650.63). A possible explanation for your weird jumping: Sometimes the changing content length also plays a role, when loading and inserting new content...

Comment: Thanks for checking it out! Glad to hear you can't replicate.

Comment: @mrjf I can understand what's your issue. Did you see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20704652/1420197)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it may be related to how this code is adding and removing the iframe every time the nav is clicked. I found that if one allows the iframe to completely load the page jump doesn't happen. In my chrome tools if I delete the iframe the jumping stops all together. I may be wrong here but if you're just showing and hiding page content when the nav is clicked, there shouldn't be a need to store the iframe in a Jquery object and then put it back in the same div container. When the iframe is put back all the calls inside the Iframe to get js resources happen again. These calls get interrupted when a user clicks a different nav element. Look in the network tab of chrome tools and you will see after clicking on all the navs that the retrieval of a resource is canceled and another has a 206 partial content in the status column. My suggestion is load the Iframe once and then hide the content when needed. I hope this was helpful good luck.

```
 b = $("#movieCtn").html(), console.log("html: ", b), $("#movieCtn").html(""),    console.log(b,$("#movieCtn").html()), $("#movieCtn").html(b))
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a good theory. It didn't end up fixing my problem but I appreciate the thought. By the way, the reason I am showing and hiding that iframe is to reset the movie player. Unfortunately that was the easiest way I found to stop it from playing once the div was hidden.