# Adding a #href anchor to a webpage

Tags: html, css, web

I want to add a `#something` to an HTML page.

An example of this would be `#History` on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow_(website).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the HTML on that page you'll see how it's being done.

The # sign in an anchor tag's href will tell the browser to move to the element that has a matching ID (where ID = everything that comes after the # sign).

For Example:

```
<a href="#MyLocation">My Link</a>

<div id="MyLocation">The anchor destination</div>
```

You can also include it at the end of your URL and it will take the user directly to the destination on page load.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow_(website)#History

Comment: Better syntax in this post, I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `name` or `id` attribute on an `<a>`nchor:

```
<a name="foo"></a>
<h1>Foo</h1>

<a id="bar"></a>
<h1>Bar</h1>
```

Pointing your link to http://www.example.com/#foo or http://www.example.com/#bar will scroll the browser down to the respective `<a>`.

The [specification of HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.1.3) lists `name` first and `id` second. (Notice the `#` in the link? You can also look at the sourcecode of the website!)

> When the name or id attributes of the A element are set, the element defines an anchor that may be the destination of other links.

According to [HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id), in HTML5 it can be `id="foo"` or `name="foo"` with `id="foo"` having precedence.

Comment: Thanks! I have a better answer.