# how to control the scrolling in webpage in jquery

Tags: jquery

when i click the link the scroll bar is going top automatically . But it should not move top. how to control that . where i clicked the control should stop there itself and show one dialog box from where it clicked .

Comment: What does clicking a link have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Probably you have an "#" as your href and an click event handler on the link? 
if so remove the click handler. Write href="javascript:yourfunction(); return false;"  This is just guessing what you might be doing...

Answer (score 0):

Read about page anchors, Google is your friend.

Here's a nice tutorial: http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/link-within-a-page.shtml

After that, read this: [HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

And once you decide to really go into it: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html