# link_to specific post using anchor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After a user posts a question i want to redirect to where its posted and scroll down to the bottom of the page where the question is, using an anchor. It seems like i'm close but the page still doesn't move. This is the link i have:

```
if @question.save
redirect_to post_comment_path(@comment.post, @comment) + "#question_#{@question.id.to_s}"
end
```

Also, the link is showing the proper id at the end like so:

```
posts/1/comments/1#question_1
```

Comment: do you include the id in the markup? `<div class="question" id="question_1">`

Comment: I'm not sure what mean. I don't want to hard code the id, i want the id to be of the new question created.

Comment: well yes, you'd generate that markup. `<%= content_tag(:div, id: "question_#{@question.id}") do %> ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, [you need to tell HTML where to "scroll" to](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html) -

> This is typically done with the `id` attribute of HTML elements, but
>   [HTML5 now allows you to use `name` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id) to achieve the same
>   thing

Bottom line is if you're appending an anchor reference to your url, the *only* way a browser will be able to access it will be with the `id` or `name` element of your page. I would do this:

```
#app/views/controller/index.html.erb
<%= @collection.each do |comment| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, class: "class", id: "question_#{comment.id}" %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to use the `comment id` directly when you send the url:

```
#question_#{@question.id.to_s}
```

Comment: Ok, bare with me.  @questions.each displays <%= question.body %>. Do i add the whole content_tag line or just attach the id inside <%= question.body %>?