# How to auto scroll to a specific table cell in a horizontal table

Tags: javascript, html

In my current project I have a table contained within a div that has 10 cells positioned horizontally. This is done using the following code below...

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="cell1"></div></td>
            <td><div id="cell2"></div></td>
            <td><div id="cell3"></div></td>
            <td><div id="cell4"></div></td>
            <td><div id="cell5"></div></td>
            <td><div id="cell6"></div></td>
            <td><div id="cell7"></div></td>
            <td><div id="cell8"></div></td>
            <td><div id="cell9"></div></td>
            <td><div id="cell10"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I already have code saying that if a user clicks on a button that corresponds to a cell in the table, the cell will highlight yellow. Since the table's width is larger than the horizontal width of the page's container, I had to set the div table overflow property to auto. How can I make it so that if the user clicks a button for a specific cell that is not **in view or only has some part of the cell in view**, the table will **auto scroll** horizontally (left or right depending on the cell's location and the current view) to that specific cell.

Is there a JavaScript solution that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Does `<a href="#cellcontent">go to cell</a>` with `<a name="cellcontent">` work? I'm not sure if it also scrolls horizontally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to scroll at any position within the same page, you can use the following:

Mark the element, where you want to scroll to, with this tag:

```
<a id="cellcontent">
```

And in order to scroll to that marker, just use a simple `a`-tag:

```
<a href="#cellcontent">go to cell</a>
```

Alternatevely, you can try it with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function showIt(elID) {
        var el = document.getElementById(elID);
        el.scrollIntoView(true);
    }    
</script>
```

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView*

**Edit:** As Pluto suggested in the comments, the better approach is to put the id-tag directly into the cell:

```
<td id="cellcontent">Some content</td>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you mean `id="cellcontent"` for the target element?

Comment: This works well when moving from right to left across the table However, when I move from the left side to the right side on button click, it only displays the right side border of the selected cell, not the entire cell.

Comment: That's because the first `a`-tag is on the left side. Try using `<a id="cellcontent">here's the cell's content</a>` instead.

Comment: @Pluto I wasn't aware of that, thx. In fact, both variants work, but id might be a bit faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Comment: @user3688513 Or instead of setting the id on the `<a>` tag, put it on the `<td>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @maja's solution, you can also do it with javascript using the cell's left position with the function `getBoundingClientRect()` minus its margin and padding. Then moving the window or scroll container to that scroll position with `element.scrollTo()` function Ex:

```
window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("cell4").getBoundingClientRect().left - 30,0);
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RXKmY/

Comment: I can't seem to get it working, when I click on the button for the corresponding cell, the webpage scrolls to the top of the page and doesn't move the table at all.

Comment: In my example I am moving the window scroll. In your case maybe the scroll is in the `div id="dashboard"` element. If that's the case, replace the `window.scrollTo` by `document.getElementById("dashboard").scrollTo`. @maja's javsacript suggestion is also valid.