# Anchor hash to the bottom of the page

Tags: html

What is the universal HTML anchor tag to go to the 'bottom' of the page? I know the tag '#' automatically brings the user to the top of the page but I am not so sure about the bottom of the page though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't one.

You can simulate it, though, with something like `<a id="bottom"></a>`, then linking to `#bottom`.

You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id) helpful, as well.

Comment: After 6 min, I will :)

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, it's better to implement this in JavaScript and definitely jump to the bottom of the page, instead of relying that the CSS styling on a link makes it always appear at the bottom of the page.

This JavaScript snippet will scroll to the bottom of the document:

```
document.body.scrollIntoView(false);
```

### Inline JavaScript solution

```
<a href="javascript: document.body.scrollIntoView(false);">Scroll to bottom</a>
```

### Separate JavaScript solution

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" id="scroll-to-bottom">Scroll to bottom</a>
```

#### JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("scroll-to-bottom").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.body.scrollIntoView(false);
});
```

Comment: That could work, but I wasn't looking for anything fancy. But this is a great answer, I'll keep this in mind, thanks :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

bung `<a name="end"></a>` at the end and then `<a href="#end">` for the link

Comment: You left out the hash in the link.

Answer (score 1):

tag #footer

and then

id the footer like so...

```
<a href="#footer">Go to bottom</a>

<footer id="footer"></footer>
```

in contrast you can tag to top of page without anchor using the # symbol only. You can use #top as well

Like so...

```
<a href="#">Go to top</a>
```