# Link to another div in another html file

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want to direct a visitor to a specific div in another html file,
This is how it goes in the same html:  `<a href="#goTo"></a>` but it doesnt work if the div is in another html. for example `<a href="../index.html #goTo">This link should go to the div goTo in the index file </a>`

Comment: index.html#goTo does thıs work? no space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space in your link:

```
<a href="../index.html#goTo">This link should go to the div goTo in the index file</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the anchor directly after the file name, without a space:

```
<a href="../index.html#goTo">This link should go to the div goTo in the index file </a>
```

If that doesn't work, check if the anchor really is named "goTo".

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are using is called [anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id).

Example:

```
<a href="#goTo">Go there</a>
[more html]
<h2 id="goTo">My GoTo Header</h2>
```

You can also adress anchors on other sites with e.g.:

```
<a href="otherSite.html#goTo">Go there</a>
```