# How can I set an anchor link to a specific section in a page?

Tags: html

I have a page, let's say page2, filled with several `<section>`:

```
<section class="box special" id="section1">
 //
</section>
<section class="box special" id="section2">
 //
</section>
<section class="box special" id="section3">
 //
</section>
<section class="box special" id="section4" style="background:#3399ff;">
 //
</section>
```

Then I have another page, page1, in which I wanna put an anchor link

```
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><a href="page2.php" class="button">Link to page2</a></li> 
   </ul>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to set up this anchors links in order to get to a specific `<section>` in page2, not just at the top of page2. Is that possible? And, if so, how?

Comment: have you tried `href="page2.php#section2`?

Comment: Two examples below are what are are after.

Comment: Nope, I wasn't aware of that, actually. Imma try that as soon as possible, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `#{id}` where `{id}` is the id value of the section you want to link to. For example

```
<a href="page2.php#section1" class="button">Link to page2</a>
```

will take you to the `section1` `section` of `page2`.

---

**Further reading:**

[MDN `href` attribute documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href)

Answer (score 7):

Use an anchor tag

```
<a name="section1"><section ...></section></a>
```

Then in the link add the specific anchor

```
<a href="page2.php#section1">Link</a>
```

And as the comments have suggested, if you're using HTML5 (and it appears you are), you can eliminate the anchor tag and just use the id of the section element

```
<section id="section1">...
```

Comment: note - in html5, the `<a name="">` is no longer needed as it can do it with the `id` attribute in `<section>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Comment: Using `<a name="">` is good if, for example, you have a really long ID, but want a short name for the link.