# What's the simplest, safest way to dynamically add anchor-able ids to HTML headers?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I want a Tumblr theme to add link-able anchors to every header in the content of a post. I don't have access to, or control over, the rendering of that content; Tumblr tends to spit out plain `<h2>`s and similar, for Markdown headers:

```
## Hello,  friend !        ->       <h2>Hello,  friend !</h2>
```

I'd like to ensure that any section of a post can be hyperlinked directly to with an [anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/484781/31897), such as `http://thing.place/post/12345#hello-friend`. Has anybody got a simple, fairly universal JavaScript snippet to sanitize any header element's content, and add it to that header as an `id`?

(Presumably, if you've already written this for yourself; you might also have some additional code to add an anchor-link indicator that self-links, as well; share it if you've got it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maintain a project that does what you describe: **AnchorJS**

- Docs: http://bryanbraun.github.io/anchorjs/
- Github Repo: https://github.com/bryanbraun/anchorjs

Once you include the script, you can pick which elements it adds anchors to with a selector:

```
// Add anchors to all h1's and h2's on the page
anchors.add('h1, h2');
```

It doesn't have any dependencies on Jquery or Lodash, in case that's an issue with Tumblr (I'm not familiar enough with Tumblr to know the constraints there).

Answer (score 0):

I've got a really naïve solution that depends upon both [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [Lodash](https://lodash.com) (and I do mean full jQuery, as Zepto and friends [don't include `:header`](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/06162793a1ec1702f68b3d7e1f539edf2fc679cc/src/selector.js#L24-L35)); but lightweight, elegant, pure-JavaScript solutions are preferred:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
   jQuery.noConflict(true)(function($){
      var lodash = _.noConflict()
        , anchor = "\u2693\uFE0E"

      $(':header')
      .wrap(function(){
         var wrapper = document.createElement('header')
           ,   title = lodash.kebabCase( $(this).text() )

         return $(wrapper).attr('id', title) })
   })
</script>
```

This does the extra work of adding a semantic `<header>` element that I'm planning on using for other purposes, but that may not be necessary.

Comment: If the only differentiating factor between jQuery and the rest is that proprietary (and confusingly named) `:header` selector, you could just expand it to its standardized equivalent. It's probably not worth including the entire jQuery library just for one selector.

Comment: Yeah, that's my assumption; but writing out all that DOM code by hand wasn't appealing. I couldn't find any question along these lines, to my surprise, here on S.O.; so I posted, in hopes somebody could one-up me with the clean equivalent for others' future discovery.