# Link to anchor on another page

Tags: html, anchor

I am looking for a way to link to an anchor on another page. I did some research already and added the `id`s in question, but it is still not working.

Here is a snippet of the code with the links:

```
<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">
    <h5 class="text-info">SALES</h5>
    <a href="sales-training-tabs.html" id="#sc">Read More &raquo;</a>
</div>
```

I would like the "Read More" links to direct users to the specified sections on the page being linked. I have several sections on the other page that look like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-lg-12">
    <h2 id="#sc">Sales Curriculum</h2>             
</div>
```

How can I link to that particular `h2` from the previous page?

Comment: What do you mean by *New way to create an achor*

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Clicking on the "Read More" works for me.

Comment: Please include code in the question it self, or better still an SO snippet, the <> button in the editor. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Basically don't give us a whole page/site to debug, just enough code to create the problem.

Comment: Waiting for the suggested edit to get rejected; I'll add in some minimal code from the site in question and clarify the question since I understood what is meant. They want to link to an anchor on another page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the hash to the "Read More" links.

That is, if you want to direct the user to the section with id `sc` on the new page, the `href` attribute should read:

```
sales_training_tabs.html#sc
```

And similarly for other `id`s.

Also, make sure the `id` attribute doesn't contain the `#`. That's strictly for the URL hash. You need `<div id="sc">`, or in your case, `<h2 id="sc">`.

Answer (score 0):

The links at the footer go nowhere `<href='#'>` 
Do this:

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="about.html">About<br>Schneider</a>
<a href="sales-consulting.html">Sales<br>Consulting</a>
<a href="sales-training.html">Sales<br>Training</a>
<a href="hiring-assessment.html">Hiring<br>Assessments</a>
<a href="mobile_learning.html">Mobile<br>Learning</a>
<a href="performance.html">Proof of<br>Performance</a>
```

The "Learn More" links open to a lightbox I assume that's how it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Well consider me told, this answer isn't valid for HTML5!

---

*Original answer:*

Purag is partially correct, you must add the hash followed by the identifier of the section in your destination URL:

```
<a href="sales-training-tabs.html#sc">Read More &raquo;</a>
```

But this does not go directly to the element with the **id** set to "sc". For this, you need to set the target section using the **name** attribute of the **a** tag:

```
<a name="sc"><h2>Sales Curriculum</h2></a>
```

Comment: So it does! Apparently I'm still stuck in 1998 mode... There is a good explanation here, including a point that `name` is no longer a valid attribute for an a tag as of HTML5: http://stackoverflow.com/a/484781/2559906

Comment: Really interesting, actually. I may be an oblivious youngster or something, but I had no idea you used to use `name` for such a thing! :P